# Socket Connection Refused (raspbian) but ports are open for connections

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, raspbian

I'd like to establish a connection between my client and raspbian. 
Within my network, I can connect to my service at any time without any problems. Now I want to connect to my service via the internet. This is unfortunately not working when I try to use my internet ip for the connection.

```
client = new MqttClient("tcp://77.777.77.77:1883", "SendingdLoop");
            client.connect();
```

My Java-Application tells me that the connection has been refused (so there is no timeout):

```
   Could not establish connection (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection **refused**: connect          at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:538)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:66)
```

I followed the official instructions to open the port:
https://wiki.debian.org/iptables

my entry looks like this:

```
 -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1883 -j ACCEPT
```

When I check iptables,

```
iptables -L
 ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere  tcp dpt: 1883
```

I can see the rule is active.

Is there anything else I have to configure?

Comment: Is the IP correct? `77.777.77.77`

Comment: thats just for the post...Like I said - the connection is refused, no timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Is there anything else I have to configure?"*

Your router, perhaps.  You really have not provided enough information to provide a definitive answer, all you've done is point out is not because of iptables...perhaps.

Iptables rules are processed *in order*. If that was the last rule appended (`-A`) and is last in the list when you look at `iptables -L`, then it can be superseded by a preceding rule.  E.g., if the list looks like:

```
DROP everything
ACCEPT everything
```

Nothing will be accepted because everthing will be dropped before the second rule is processed (more exactly, the second rule will never be processed because everything will find a match in the first rule).

Comment: my router forwarded the connection from 1883 to 80 so your answer is correct. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `mqtt` broker called `vernemq`, but solved it by adding the following.

1. `$ sudo vmq-admin listener show`

   To show the list `o` allowed IP's and ports for `vernemq`
2. `$ sudo vmq-admin listener start port=1885 -a 0.0.0.0 --mountpoint /appname --nr_of_acceptors=10 --max_connections=20000`

   To add any IP and your new port. Now you should be able to connect without any problem.